# Removing XMPPFramework causes CoreData crash

Tags: ios, core-data, xmppframework

I removed XMPPFramework from my project because I no longer needed it. However, my app now crashes due to a CoreData migration problem. All of the Core Data entities that XMPPFramework added are now gone from my data model (obviously) but Core Data fails to recover from this data model change and crashes. How can I migrate my data model to incorporate the fact that all these tables are missing from my data model?

Example:
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {

```
        Message = <a4ab6db8 >;

        EXAMPLE1 = <6ac82d7d >;

        EXAMPLE2 = <7dcb3fdc >;

        EXAMPLE3 = <57b68932 >;

        EXAMPLE4 = <64ea72d1 >;

        Service = <5bfb096d >;

        XMPPCapsCoreDataStorageObject = <fcc8a450 >;

        XMPPCapsResourceCoreDataStorageObject = <b4ad78f7 >;

        XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject = <2d9d5e0b >;

        "XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject" = <b35921c6 >;

        "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" = <55ad74f0 >;

        XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject = <e31f4b20 >;

        XMPPRoomMessageCoreDataStorageObject = <e93f6bf3 >;

        XMPPRoomMessageHybridCoreDataStorageObject = <13824bff >;

        XMPPRoomOccupantCoreDataStorageObject = <2848335c >;

        XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject = <0ef429b0 >;

        XMPPvCardAvatarCoreDataStorageObject = <66d4bf5e >;

        XMPPvCardCoreDataStorageObject = <adac5b15 >;

        XMPPvCardTempCoreDataStorageObject = <8a708229 >;

    };
```

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator's current model hashes are {

```
        EXAMPLE1 = <6ac82d7d >;

        EXAMPLE2 = <7dcb3fdc >;

        EXAMPLE3 = <57b68932 >;

        EXAMPLE4 = <64ea72d1 >;
```

}

So as you can see, all the XMPP related managed objects are gone, and the lightweight migration failed. I need help making a custom migration to the new data model. Please help!

-Sunny

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely when you removed the framework you lost part of your model for Core Data (although I am not familiar with that framework).  Assuming the error is a failure to migrate you need to get your old data model back and create a new data model without those tables so that Core Data can find the source and destination models for its lightweight migration.  Without both models, Core Data cannot do the migration.